# Installing APC on Centos PHP7

Tags: installation, centos, php-7, apc

I am trying to get the modules installed for an old Symfony site.

I tried

```
sudo yum install php-pecl-apc
```

returned

```
No package php-pecl-apc available.
```

I can't apt-get s it is not installed. How can I get this module installed

Answer (score 0):

php-pecl-apc is not available for centos7, so you need to install php73-php-pecl-apcu.

Note- not available in official centos repo, so you have to use Remi repo.

https://centos.pkgs.org/7/remi-x86_64/php73-php-pecl-apcu-5.1.17-1.el7.remi.x86_64.rpm.html

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[APC](https://pecl.php.net/package/APC) is a dead project, no stable version was released for any version of PHP > 5.3.

For **opcode cache**, the [opcache](https://pecl.php.net/package/ZendOpcache) extension exists for PHP 5.x and is now part of PHP 7.x

For **user data cache**, the [APCu](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCU) extension version 4 exists for **PHP 5.x** and provides a new API, and a compatibility layer to emulate APC

For **PHP 7.x**, **APCU** version 5 only provides the new API, but the [apcu_bc](https://pecl.php.net/package/APCu_bc) extension provides the compatibility layer.

How do you install PHP 7 on your CentOS box ? Good package providers have these extensions available (php-pecl-apcu and php-pecl-apcu-bc).

P.S. "[remi](https://rpms.remirepo.net/)" repository is a possible provider for PHP and its extensions, follow the [wizard instuctions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/).